# Common interface for different objects of a template class

Tags: c++, c++11

New to C++ and came across some code like this (also not sure whether this is the right way to do)

```
template<ReqType, RespType>
class StreamManager {
...
...
}

using UpstreamManager = StreamManager<UpstreamReq, UpstreamResp>;
using DownstreamManager = StreamManager<DownstreamReq, DownstreamResp>;
using SidestreamManager = StreamManager<SidestreamReq, SidestreamResp>;
```

I want to implement a function that returns one of these types depending on the type passed to the function. Is there a way to define it to be of some common type.

```
**[ReturnType]** CreateStreamManager(StreamType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case upstream:
            return new UpstreamManager();
        case downstream:
            return new DownstreamManager();
        case sidestream:
            return new SidestreamManager();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to define this **ReturnType** for this CreateStreamManager function ?

Comment: What is the meaning of `template<ReqType, RespType>`? Here `ReqType` and `RespType` are types or type parameters?

Comment: Also, what is `StreamType`?

Answer (score 2):

You can "overload" the function, like this:

```
UpstreamManager* CreateStreamManager(UpstreamReq req) {
    return new UpstreamManager();
}
DownstreamManager* CreateStreamManager(DownstreamReq req) {
    return new DownstreamManager();
}
```

Or you can write a "factory function", but only if `StreamManager` inherits a non-template base class which can be the common return type:

```
class BaseStreamManager {
    virtual ~BaseStreamManager() = default;
};

template<ReqType, RespType>
class StreamManager : public BaseStreamManager {
}

BaseStreamManager* CreateStreamManager(StreamType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case upstream:
            return new UpstreamManager();
        case downstream:
            return new DownstreamManager();
        case sidestream:
            return new SidestreamManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think returning `std::unique_ptr<BaseStreamManager>` is more preferable. But this is a trivial matter.

Answer (score 0):

From C++17 (I'm not sure), you can use `auto` specifier as return type. I would define the function like this:

```
template<typename ReqType, typename RespType>
auto CreateStreamManager() {
    return new StreamManager<ReqType, RespType>();
}
```

If the type can be determined at compile time, you can also use `constexpr` specifier:

```
constexpr auto CreateStreamManager(StreamType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case upstream:
        return new UpStreamManager();
    ...
}
```

By the way, it is bad to allocate memory and return it without smart pointers.

Comment: `auto function` has been around since C++14, but the question is tagged C++11. And while using smart pointers are safer, some older code bases might rely on raw pointers for compatibility.